# Launch a program to run on a specific display

Tags: xorg, display, display-manager

- I have two displays on my PC, say `Display1` & `Display2`.
- `Display2` is configured as an extension to `Display1`.
- Being on `Display1` I wish to launch (from a terminal emulator),  an application say `xcalc`, which should pop up on `Display2`.
   Is it possible somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Some programs are smart enough to remember the last window position.
- Many programs written for the X Window System accept a `-geometry` option; for example, `xcalc -geometry +500+750` will start `xcalc` placing the window 500 pixels to right and 750 pixels down from the logical upper-left corner (which is +0+0). Other programs call this option `--geometry` (note then two hyphens). Read the documentation of the specific program.
- Another option is to install `wmctrl` (`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`). `wmctrl` (Window Manager Control) allows sending requests to the window manager to perform certain actions, such as resizing or moving windows. You could then write a small script which starts the program and then uses wmctrl to move it where you want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

"First you'll need to find out what DISPLAY is set to in the X session where you want your program to run. Do this by issuing the command echo $DISPLAY inside an X-terminal in that X session. Typically get something like :0.0 is outputted.

Lets say you want to start the excellent program xclock program in your X session where DISPLAY is :0.0, but you want to do this at the console. You then press Alt-Ctrl-F1 to shift to that console, and then type:

DISPLAY=:0.0 xclock   # variables set w/ a command are local to that command."

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101713/is-it-possible-to-choose-which-x-display-a-program-instance-should-run-on